# sendmail: recipients with -t option not supported on Linux 3.2.12-gentoo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, email

I am working on an application in ruby on rails where an email is generated when user clicks con forgot password  after giving his username. the new password is sent to him via an email. 
I have Linux 3.2.12-gentoo vps where my application deployed. the code for sending email is under the following.
**Notifier.rb**

```
def send_password ( email, user )
    @password = user.UserPassword
    mail :to => "#{email}",
         :subject => "Your new TrackerPal password."
end
```

**development.rb**

```
require 'tlsmail'
#Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)

ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {    
  :address  => "mail.securealert.com",
  :port  => 25,   
  :domain  => "mail.securealert.com",  
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => "",
  :password => ""
}
```

The code gets executed and I could see an email template being generated for new password along with a message i.e. 
**sendmail:  recipients with -t option not supported**
The same code is on another linux debian system which works absolutely fine and I received email from there.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456205/rails-sendmail-recipients-with-t-option-not-supported

Comment: Uri Agassi. I don't have /initializers/setup_mail.rb under config folder but 
wrap_parameters.rb
session_store.rb
secret_tokent.rb
mime_types.rb
inflections.rb
backtrace_silencers.rb